# Tuple member extraction in closure arguments

Tags: swift, tuples

Considering this array of tuple :

```
var tupleArray = [(String, Int)]()
tupleArray.append(("bonjour", 2))
tupleArray.append(("Allo", 1))
tupleArray.sort { (t1 , t2) -> Bool in
    let (_, n1) = t1
    let (_, n2) = t2
    return n1 < n2
}
```

I would like to make the closure shorter by doing something like this :

```
tupleArray.sort { ((_, n1) , (_, n2)) -> Bool in
    n1 < n2
}
```

First: is it possible?
Second: if possible what is the syntaxe?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use short closure syntax:

```
tupleArray.sort { $0.1 < $1.1 }
```

See [the official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) about short closure syntax, the `.1` is just tuple index access.

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of this one, but is there a way to directly extra the $0.1 into its own variable? (in the argument list of the closure)